# How do I create something like this that has to be put in a database

Tags: database, flask

[what I a trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ekN3.jpg)I am trying to create a pill tracker for a demo project, but I am stuck. I want to create something like this(attached in the picture but I have no idea oh how to do so.) Any relevant articles or doc will be helpful.

I figured I that I have to create the dB, which I already did but that's it. I have no idea on how to move on.